# Plotting Differential Equation Phase Diagrams

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I haven't got Matlab, nor have I found a suitable online tool. Could someone plot the phase diagram for the following, or point me in the right direction?

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = y - x, \frac{dy}{dt} = x(4 - y)$$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use [WolframAlpha](http://goo.gl/0P4vG0):

```
stream plot (y-x,x(4-y)), x=-1..5, y=-1..5
```

[image]

It's always nice to verify this sort of thing with analytic tools.  The equilibria satisfy

\begin{align}
 y-x &= 0 \\
 x(4-y) &= 0
\end{align}

From the second equation, $x=0$ or $y=4$.  From the first equation, $x=y$.  Thus, there are two equilibria at the points $(0,0)$ and $(4,4)$.  The nature of the equilibria can be determined from the eigenvalues of the matrix
$$
\left(
 \begin{array}{cc}
   -1 & 1 \\
   4-y & -x
 \end{array}
\right)
$$
The rows are the partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ of the system.  At $x=y=4$, the eigenvalues are $-4$ and $-1$ and at $x=y=0$, there is one positive eigenvalue and one negative eigenvalue.  This is consistent with the picture.

Comment: Is your Jacobian matrix correct? Surely it should be 4 - y in the bottom left entry?

Comment: @Brian Surely..

Comment: . . . Partially differentiate x(4-y) with respect to x?

Comment: @Brian I agreed with you once already! :)

Comment: I thought the .. were sarcastic, my bad.

Comment: @Brian Sorry. Actually, the two dots arose because I was one character short of the minimum requirement with just one. :)  Will fix soon.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `octave` instead (this is a free and open clone of `matlab`). You can assess your ODE system by a vector function such as:

```
function dx = f(x,t)
   dx(1) = x(2) - x(1);
   dx(2) = x(1)*(4-x(2));
end
```

Then you can solve it using `lsode` method for a given set of initial condition on a defined time range:

```
xs = lsode(@f,[1,2],0:0.01:10);
```

You can also plot the vector field associated with the system using `quiver` function. Printing `xs` over it give you the trajectory for the initial conditions you have chosen. By plotting several trajectories you will get a preciser idea of phase diagram associated with.

The following plots have been produced with octave using the above procedure:

[image: Solutions]
[image: Phase Diagram]