# Drawing Plausible Phase Portrait

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The equation:

$$\dot{x} = f(x),\space x\in \mathbb{R},\space \text{where} \space f\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 3x_1^2 + 7x_1x_2 + x_1 + 2x_2^2 -x_2\\
-12x_1^2-16x_1x_2-3x_1 -x_2\end{pmatrix}$$

I want to draw the plausible phase portrait for this whole system. Is there any software where I can draw this?

I already drew the phase portrait in a neighborhood of x*

[Click Here For Phase Portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wggCJ.png)

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/680852/418542) for a Matlab solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is in Mathematica's Streamplot command

[image]

You can also try [*Maxima*](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/), [*SAGE*](http://www.sagemath.org/), [*PPLANE*](http://math.rice.edu/~dfield/dfpp.html), [*Phase Portrait Generator*](http://parasolarchives.com/tools/phaseportrait) or many others.

For example, many [*Computer Algebra Systems*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems) can also do these plots.

Lastly, you can try [*OCTAVE*](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), which is a MatLab clone and here is a post (see answers) showing the commands [Plotting Differential Equation Phase Diagrams](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822092/plotting-differential-equation-phase-diagrams) and these [*answers*](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/phase-portrait-td1622682.html).