# Biological model of integrate-and-fire neurons

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, biology

I need help in solving a set of equations.

*Background*: I'd like to model the firing rate of an integrate-and-fire neuron depending on the supply of usable energy that is available. (I don't know how biologically plausible this model is, but first I'd like to solve it.)

The variables (all of them time-dependent):

- $\nu$: the firing rate of the neuron
- $E$: the supply of usable energy (e.g. to drive the [ion pumps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Na%2B/K%2B-ATPase))
- $P$: the production rate of usable energy
- $L$: the loss rate of usable energy

Some constants (depending on the physiology of the neuron):

- $\nu_{max}$: the maximal firing rate (e.g. 100Hz)
- $E_{min}$: the minimal energy supply that is needed to maintain $\nu_{max}$
- $P_0$: base production rate

The initial conditions:

- $E_0 > E_{min}$, i.e. the energy store is full
- $\nu_0 = \nu_{max}$, i.e. the neuron fires maximally

**Important note**: The neuron is - from the beginning - exposed to a constant stimulus (e.g. an current injected near the axon hillock) which is strong enough to evoke maximal firing.

Now to the set of equations I'd like to solve:

> - $\nu(E) = \nu_{max} \min\{1,E/E_{min}\}$ (without energy no firing is possible)
> - $\dot{E} = P - L$
> - $L = \lambda\ \nu$
> - $P = P_0 + p\ \nu$

I am looking for the firing rate $\nu$ and the energy supply $E$ as explicit functions of time, depending on the parameters $E_{min}$, $P_0$, $p$, and $\lambda$, where $p < \lambda$ is assumed.

Is the problem well-posed?

Any hint to which method (better: tool) to use is welcome!

(The first part of the curves is easy: the $\nu$ curve is constantly at $\nu_{max}$, the $E$ curve decreases linearly with constant negative slope $\dot{E} = P_0 + (p - \lambda)\nu_{max}$ (i.e.  $P_0 < (\lambda - p)\nu_{max}$ is required). When $E$ reaches $E_{min}$, something else starts to happen, possibly a synchronized oscillation of $\nu$ and $E$ around each other. But what about the amplitudes and frequency of these oscillations in the long-term limit?)

Thanks to Evgeny's comment, the question can be put much simpler: What are the solutions of

$$\dot{E} = \alpha - \beta\min\{1,\gamma E\}$$

with $\alpha < \beta$?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that this can be gathered into one equation for $E$, namely $\dot{E} = P_0 + (p - \lambda) \cdot \nu_{\rm max} \cdot \max{\lbrace 1, E/E_{\rm min} \rbrace}$?

Comment: Good, in that case you have an autonomous dynamical system. Do you know how to plot phase portrait for 1d autonomous systems?

Comment: @Evgeny: Can you recommend a tool for plotting phase portraits?

Comment: In that case pen and paper would be enough :) You can look at one of chapters in Strogatz book, he explains that pretty good. But what's worrying me here is that $\dot{E}$ is always negative and thus $E$ is always decreasing and I think that this is not what you want. Or is it?

Comment: Unfortunately, you are right again! How do I have to implement a mechanism into the equation that allows the neuron to refill its energy store while firing?

Comment: I made a bad mistake: it must be min, not max! I'll correct this immediately.

Comment: @Evgeny: I found out how to plot phase portraits of two-dimensional systems with [Wolfram Alpha](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822092/plotting-differential-equation-phase-diagrams). But what to enter at WA in my case?

Comment: Something like `stream plot (A - B * min(1, G*x), 1), x=-1..5, y=-1..5` . It's equivalent to $\dot{x} = A - B \cdot \min{\lbrace 1, Gx \rbrace}, \; \dot{y} = 1$ which is equivalent to $\frac{dx}{dy} = A - B \cdot \min{\lbrace 1, Gx \rbrace}$. By the way, since you've changed the equations everything is pretty okay now: this system has a stable equilibrium.

Comment: Unfortunately, [it doesn't work](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=stream+plot+(A+-+B+*+min(1,+G*x),+1),+x%3D-1..5,+y%3D-1..5).

Comment: Hm, seems that Wolfram Alpha doesn't understand $\min$ operator in differential equation. By the way, besides that I've forgot that we should plug constants instead of $A$, $B$, $G$, I can't even plot the simplest streamplot with WA.