# What does it mean $y'=f(y)$, where $f(y)$ is a function in $y$, geometrically?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

When learning to solve ODEs, we encounter with the ODE defining the exponential function: $y'=y$. And more generally $y'=r\ y$, where $r\in\Bbb R$. For solving this problem, we can use separation of variables, solving the characteristic polynomial, etc. But I don't understant how to grasp the picture in a geometrical way.

If we have the ODE $y'=1$, then solving using the common technics, we conclude that $y=x+c$, but for another case, What happend for the ODE $y'=H(y)$, where $H(y)$ is the Heaviside step function? And we have the following graph...

[image: Heaviside step function equal to y']

If I tried to solve it and pass the antiderivative operation to the defintion of $H(y)$...

$$y'=H(y)=
\begin{cases}
1,& y\geq0 \\[2ex]
0,& y<0
\end{cases}
$$

$$\int y'dx=\int H(y) dx=
\begin{cases}
\int 1dx,& y\geq0 \\[2ex]
\int 0dx,& y<0
\end{cases}
$$

$$y=\begin{cases}
x+c,& y\geq0 \\[2ex]
c,& y<0
\end{cases} $$

and now What can I do with the conditions with respect of $y$? This result seems incorrect because is a circular defintion of $y$.

Comment: As trulia suggests in his answer: the **geometric** meaning is the phase diagram.  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/822092/442

Comment: @GEdgar thanks so much. To portrait a phase diagram with the ODE i tried to solve, How can i do it?

Comment: You can easily rewrite your final solution if you recast the problem as an initial value problem with initial condition $y(0)=c$: $$y(x) = \begin{cases}
x+c,& c\geq0 \\[2ex]
c,& c<0
\end{cases} $$

Comment: @LeeMosher Suppose that $c=2$, then the condition $c\geq 0$ is always meet and then $y(x)=x+2$ instead of the piecewise definition?

Answer (score 1):

Your DE $y'=H(y)$ has various soluions.  For example: $y=c$ for any constant $c<0$.  Or $y=x+c$ for any constant $c$, restricted to $x>{-c}$.

[image: a]

Comment: Can you provide a bit of insight please?

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to solve by separation of variables you should see
with y(x) that dy/f(y)=dx and you can not just write y'=f(y) and
$\int y'(x)dx= \int f(y(x))dx $ and then use instead of f(y(x))= just f(x) what you did with H(y(x)) . Geometrically it says that in the phase diagran you have constant incline for y=const

Comment: So solving $\int_{[0,y]}dt/H(t)=x$, then $y=x+c\ \forall y\geq 0$ and for $y<0$ the integral is undefine?